# How to avoid that Karate fixes the json payload automatically?

Tags: karate

I see that Karate automatically fix the json when a key doesn't have a value ({date:, name:"carl"}). How can I avoid that Karate fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a string data type and force a header if needed, note the quotes around the `request` body.

```
Given url 'http://httpbin.org'
And path 'post'
And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
And request '{ date:, name:"carl" }'
When method post
Then status 200
```

Also refer the docs on [type conversion](https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion).